# Chat message box as wide as text content

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview-layout

So i want to have chat message container as wide as the message is.
I want to achieve something really similiar to this kind of chat message:
http://img.creativemark.co.uk/uploads/images/805/15805/img3File.png

Here is my layout, with which i am struggling:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/single_message_view"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="author"
            android:id="@+id/sender_data"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:id="@+id/send_date" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/message_content"
        android:background="@drawable/msg_haze"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:text="content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/message_text"
            android:id="@+id/tags_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/message_tags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_tag" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/message_state" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/attachment_holder"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/attachments_haze">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/attachments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attachment"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To display the chat Message you need to use 9 patch images that allows you to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view

Answer (score 1):

Usually for this type of chat bubble we need to use [the nine patch image](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html). This nine patch image can re-size according to content inside.

Below are nine patch image for send and receive message.

[image]

[image]

Save this image as `.9.png` extension. Use this image to give background.

Comment: i think, this wont be necessary for this particular question as if you can open the image reference in the question, there is a simple square box enclosure with flat color which can be obtained using a drawable itself. No need for a 9 patch image. Just set the layout logically using a color drawable for background purpose. Posting the whole layout in a while.

Comment: Yeah that is also possible. but that is only reference. Most of (not all) chat bubbles are made of the nine patch image.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, that is y i mentioned "this wont be necessary for this particular problem"

Comment: @Mit I don't know exactly what do you mean by this. Can you provide the code implementation?

Comment: yes buddy, i am posting the same in a while, and i am just telling you are absolutely right, most of the chat bubble need 9 patch image, but for this particular question it is not necessary, that is what i am trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

agree with @basavannevva .. 9 patch image automatically stretches .. you have to provide its content area and stretch area. there are plenty of online tools that can create a 9 patch image. and i think even android studio can edit 9 patch file.

Answer (score 0):

temp_black.xml (This will be used as a background of the chat box, you can change the color in the below file to #FFFFFF to get the desired output)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#000000"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```

temp_white.xml (This is the black dot between the Name of Sender and Time, i know in the image the color is black, but for reference purpose i have made this, you cant just edit the color in below xml to get the output of your choice)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <corners android:radius="100dip" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```

temp.xml (The layout file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/temp_black"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="Sample Text Sample Text"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/temp_white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the output image
[image]

Comment: just change the layout gravity to right|center_vertical for displaying the chat box on other side, if required, do let me know, i can provide you with both sides included